# Class "OpenAI" not found

Tags: php, openai-api

I'm trying to use the OpenAI API client for PHP, following [these instructions](https://github.com/openai-php/client?tab=readme-ov-file)

Installing the libraries seemed to go fine:

```
composer require openai-php/client
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

And the relevant initial fragment of PHP:

```
$yourApiKey = getenv('YOUR_API_KEY');
$client = OpenAI::client($yourApiKey);
```

Which gets this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "OpenAI" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php:13 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 13

Looking at answers to adjacent questions, there is the insertion of an initial line of code:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Tried; no difference.

Some people seem to be saying the last line needs to be modified with an explicit scope prefix:

```
$client = \OpenAI::client($yourApiKey);
```

Tried; no difference.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix found! I had my code in `C:\xampp\htdocs` as the simplest way to start. Maybe some of the other stuff XAMPP puts there by default was confusing PHP, for creating a subdirectory `C:\xampp\htdocs\openai` and putting my code (`test.php` and the `vendor` directory and associated files created by Composer) into it, caused the test to succeed.